# Implementing Quicksort to sort a list with restricted/no access to its contents

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

I'm trying to implement the Quicksort algorithm to sort a list which does not directly allow access to its elements.  I'm supposed to sort the  `list` using only two methods: `swap` and `compare` , without using the `toString`method provided only for debugging purposes. I have chosen the middle element of the sub-array as the pivot. Comparisons are made using the `Comparator` object passed during the function call.

I ran a few JUnit tests with randomly generated lists <s>out of which almost all are getting sorted</s> (**Update**: After running a few more tests, I found many more cases where the algorithm failed). However, (one of the cases where) my algorithm fails when I try to `partition` a 4 element sub-array with the keys arranged in this order: [smallest, biggest, big, small]

Here's the JUnitTest passing the list - [0, 3, 2 ,1]:

```
private static final Comparator<Integer> INTEGER_COMPARATOR = new IntegerComparator();
@Test
public void customTest() {
    SwapList<Integer> customList;
    AbstractSorter<Integer> customSorter;
    customList = new ArrayBasedSwapList<Integer>(new Integer[] { 0, 3, 2, 1 });
    customSorter = new QuickSorter<Integer>(customList,
            INTEGER_COMPARATOR);
    SwapList<Integer> result = customSorter.sort();
    System.out.println("Result: " + result.toString());
    assertTrue(result.isSorted(INTEGER_COMPARATOR));
}
```

and the `IntegerComparator` class used:

```
package comparators;

import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * Comparator on two Integers in the usual order.
 * 
 * @author liberato
 *
 */
public class IntegerComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```

I put some println statements and added an `indent` variable in the code for debugging purposes. Here's the output after running the test:

```
quicksort(0, 3)  
  Inside partition(0, 3)  
  pivotIndex = 1  
  Initially: [0, 3, 2, 1]  
  i = 1, pivotIndex = 1, j = 3  
  After 1st swap: [0, 1, 2, 3]  
  Pivot was swapped  
  i = 2, pivotIndex = 3, j = 2  
  After 2nd swap: [0, 1, 3, 2]  
  i = 2, pivotIndex = 3, j = 2  
  p = 2  
  quicksort(0, 1)  
    Inside partition(0, 1)  
    pivotIndex = 0  
    Initially: [0, 1, 3, 2]  
    i = 0, pivotIndex = 0, j = 0  
    After 2nd swap: [0, 1, 3, 2]  
    i = 0, pivotIndex = 0, j = 0  
    p = 0  
    quicksort(0, -1)  
    quicksort(1, 1)  
  quicksort(3, 3)
```

Result: [0, 1, 3, 2]

The problem is inside `partition(0, 3)` where the second swap statement reverses the effect of the first swap. Can someone help with correcting my quick sort algorithm? I should perhaps add an `if` statement so that the second swap occurs only if element at index `i` > element at `pivotIndex`?

Here's the code:

```java
package sorters;

import java.util.Comparator;

import structures.SwapList;

public class QuickSorter<T> extends AbstractSorter<T> {
    //String indent = "";
    public QuickSorter(SwapList<T> list, Comparator<T> comparator) {
        super(list, comparator);
    }

    @Override
    public SwapList<T> sort() {
        quicksort(0, list.size() - 1);
        return list;
    }

    private void quicksort(int firstIndex, int lastIndex) {
        //System.out.println(indent + "quicksort(" + firstIndex + ", " + lastIndex + ")");
        //indent+="  ";
        if(firstIndex < lastIndex) {
            int p = partition(firstIndex, lastIndex);
            //System.out.println(indent + "p = " + p);
            quicksort(firstIndex, p - 1);
            quicksort(p + 1, lastIndex);
        }
        //indent = indent.substring(2);
    }

    private int partition(int firstIndex, int lastIndex) {
        //System.out.println(indent + "Inside partition(" + firstIndex + ", " + lastIndex + ")");
        int pivotIndex = (firstIndex + lastIndex) / 2;
        //System.out.println(indent + "pivotIndex = " + pivotIndex);
        int i = firstIndex;
        int j = lastIndex;
        while (i < j) {
            while(list.compare(i, pivotIndex, comparator) < 0 && i < j) {
                i++;
            }
            while(list.compare(j, pivotIndex, comparator) >= 0 && i < j) {
                j--;
            }
            //System.out.println(indent + "Initially: " + list.toString());
            //System.out.println(indent + "i = " + i +", pivotIndex = " + pivotIndex + ", j = " + j);
            if(i < j) {
                list.swap(i, j);
                //System.out.println(indent + "After 1st swap: " + list.toString());
                if(i == pivotIndex) {
                    pivotIndex = j;
                    //System.out.println(indent + "Pivot was swapped");
                }
                else if(j == pivotIndex) {
                    pivotIndex = i;
                    //System.out.println(indent + "Pivot was swapped");
                }
                i++;
                j--;
                //System.out.println(indent + "i = " + i +", pivotIndex = " + pivotIndex + ", j = " + j);
            }
        }
        list.swap(pivotIndex, i);
        //System.out.println(indent + "After 2nd swap: " + list.toString());
        //System.out.println(indent + "i = " + i +", pivotIndex = " + pivotIndex + ", j = " + j);
        return i;
    }
}
```

**Additional Code:**

As requested in the comments section -

The superclass `AbstractSorter<T>`:

```
package sorters;

import java.util.Comparator;

import structures.SwapList;

/**
 * An abstraction over the idea of a sorter. Concrete subclasses should sort the
 * list into ascending (smallest-first) order, using the provided Comparator.
 * 
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public abstract class AbstractSorter<T> {
    /**
     * the list to be sorted
     */
    protected final SwapList<T> list;

    /**
     * the comparator to be used
     */
    protected final Comparator<T> comparator;

    /**
     * Constructs a new sorter, using the given list and comparator.
     * @param list the list to be sorted
     * @param comparator the comparator to use when sorting
     * @throw IllegalStateException if the list has already been manipulated by a sorter
     */
    public AbstractSorter(SwapList<T> list, Comparator<T> comparator) {
        if ((list == null) || (comparator == null)) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        if (list.getComparisons() > 0 || list.getSwaps() > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        this.list = list;
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the associated list in-place, and returns a reference to it. 
     * 
     * @return a reference to the sorted list.
     */
    public abstract SwapList<T> sort();
}
```

The interface `SwapList<T>`:

```
package structures;

import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * A list which supports the minimal operations necessary for most in-place
 * comparison-based sorts, along with two observers.
 * 
 * Notably, it does not (directly) allow access to specific elements, though
 * though a toString() method is included in ArrayBasedSwapList for fans of caveman
 * debugging.
 * 
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public interface SwapList<T> {
    /**
     * Return the result of comparator.compare() on the two elements of the list
     * at the given indices.
     * 
     * @param index1
     * @param index2
     * @param comparator
     * @return the result of comparator.compare() on the values at the indices
     */
    public int compare(int index1, int index2, Comparator<T> comparator);

    /**
     * Swaps the values contained in the indices of the list.
     * @param index1
     * @param index2
     */
    public void swap(int index1, int index2);

    /**
     * 
     * @return the number of elements in the list
     */
    public int size();

    /**
     * 
     * @param comparator
     * @return true iff the list is sorted according to the given comparator
     */
    public boolean isSorted(Comparator<T> comparator);

    /**
     * 
     * @return the number of times swap() has been called on this list
     */
    public int getSwaps();

    /**
     * 
     * @return the number of times compare() has been called on this list
     */
    public int getComparisons();
}
```

And the implementing class `ArrayBasedSwapList<T>`:

```
package structures;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class ArrayBasedSwapList<T> implements SwapList<T> {
    private final ArrayList<T> arrayList;
    private int swaps = 0;
    private int comparisons = 0;

    public ArrayBasedSwapList(T[] array) {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(array));
    }

    public ArrayBasedSwapList(Collection<T> coll) {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<T>(coll);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(int index1, int index2, Comparator<T> comparator) {
        comparisons++;
        return comparator.compare(arrayList.get(index1), arrayList.get(index2));
    }

    @Override
    public void swap(int index1, int index2) {
        swaps++;
        T temp = arrayList.get(index1);
        arrayList.set(index1, arrayList.get(index2));
        arrayList.set(index2, temp);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSorted(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (comparator.compare(arrayList.get(i), arrayList.get(i + 1)) > 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int getSwaps() {
        return swaps;
    }

    public int getComparisons() {
        return comparisons;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return arrayList.toString();
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Implementing the suggestions in @ruakh's answer, I was able to debug and identify the problem. The fault was in the `partition` method. Here's the corrected algorithm:

```
int partition(int firstIndex, int lastIndex) {
    int pivotIndex = (firstIndex + lastIndex) / 2;
    int i = firstIndex;
    int j = lastIndex;
    while (i < j) {
        while(i < lastIndex && list.compare(i, pivotIndex, comparator) <= 0 && i <= pivotIndex) {
            i++;
        }
        if(i < pivotIndex) {
            list.swap(i, pivotIndex);
            pivotIndex = i;
        }

        while(firstIndex < j && list.compare(j, pivotIndex, comparator) >= 0 && pivotIndex <= j) {
            j--;
        }

        if(j > pivotIndex) {
            list.swap(j, pivotIndex);
            pivotIndex = j;
        }
    }
    return pivotIndex;
}
```

Comment: please add full code to your question

Comment: I suggest reading [Eric Lippert's "How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You will learn much more by debugging this yourself, and finding the bug(s), than by getting strangers on the Internet to find the bug and just tell you about it.

Comment: @Amit: Some people like debuggers. Others don't. (I'm in the latter camp, personally.) The problem here may be that the OP hasn't debugged, but it certainly isn't that (s)he hasn't "use[d] a debugger".

Comment: @ruakh - it seems like you're suggesting my comment is not in place... I still think OP should be using a debugger (and by using a debugger I mean using it to debug the program, not to make a salad) It also seems you think the same...

Comment: @Amit: No, I do *not* think the same. Use of a debugger to debug is a matter of personal preference; your comment is not much better than posting "Use Haskell."

Comment: @ruakh - had I commented "use Haskell." You'd probably not reply with a message about **debugging**, which you did, and I really don't understand your insistence to argue on something we both agree on - OP should have debugged his code. A *debugger* is the de-facto standard tool used to *debug*. If you have other ideas or preferences, feel free to express them but please stop trying to pull me into an argument.

Comment: @Amit Thanks for the suggestion. I'll learn how to use a debugger, in the meanwhile, I've resorted to caveman debugging with println statements.

Comment: @JavaHopper Added the entire code plus a JUnit test along with its output.

Comment: Code for structures.SwapList is missing. Also, were you able to fix the issue or still stuck around?

Comment: @ruakh Thanks for the link. I'd debugged the code earlier but didn't include it because I thought the println statements would make the algorithm less readable. I've added them as comments now along with the specific bug I'm encountering.

Comment: @JavaHopper I wasn't able the fix the issue but have managed to find (one of)the problem case(s). When you say you want the entire code, are you asking for all the classes whose objects are used or do you want just the ones in the import statement?

Comment: only that part of code, which participates in your sorting and the dependent classes. for example, structures.SwapList in this case

Comment: @JavaHopper Added relevant code now.

Comment: @Amit: Re: "A debugger is the de-facto standard tool used to debug": I don't think so. Code inspection, testing, and logging are all used at least as widely. (I have nothing against people who find debuggers useful; more power to them. It's a perfectly fine suggestion. But flatly telling someone "Use a debugger" is not "being drawn into an argument", it is *starting* one. :-) )

Comment: @ruakh apart from logging (which at best is handicapped debugging) the other methods are used to create working code (and are great practices to limit the need for debugging), but are definitely not methods for debugging. A test can't tell you *why* it's failing, it can only tell you that *it is* failing. The debugger let's you identify the exact cause of a bug.

Comment: @Amit: Good tests help you identify the exact thing that's failing.

Comment: Yes, like @ruakh said, ByteMan2021's assumption that list of size 4 with format [smallest, biggest, big, small] fails is wrong. I have another test case, which is of size 5 - [7, 3, 1, 6, 6] and this fails too.

Comment: @ByteMan2021, is that fine if I rewrite your algorithm?

Comment: @JavaHopper Of course, I was just generalising the list that I tested for which was, as I stated before, "(one of)the problem case(s)" - I didn't imply that it was the only one. After a few more rounds of debugging and running some more tests, I've found a few more cases where the algorithm fails. It would be great if you could correct/make changes to the existing algorithm. In the meanwhile, I'll have a look at ruakh's answer and see if I can fix what's wrong.

Comment: @ByteMan2021, any reason why you decided to chose middle element as pivot?

Comment: @JavaHopper That's because its part of an assignment and the specifications state that the middle element must be selected for the pivot. The assignment itself is from a data structures course that my friend did last year so before you ask, no, it's not part of my homework.

Comment: @ByteMan2021, finally! after lot of debugging. I added working code in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three mistakes or arguable mistakes in the `partition` method:

- The method is `private`, which means that you're not unit-testing it, even though it's one of the most complex pieces of code you've got.

  - You can address this either by making it package-private (some APIs, such as Guava, offer a special `@VisibleForTesting` annotation that you can use to make clear why you've done this), or by factoring it out into its own class that `QuickSorter` delegates to.
- Your algorithm assumes that `i <= pivotIndex && pivotIndex <= j` at all times (since otherwise `list.swap(i, j)` accomplishes nothing), but it only ensures that `i <= j`.

  - I determined this by code inspection, but once I saw the bug, I checked your debugging output, and in fact this issue did show up there: `i = 2, pivotIndex = 3, j = 2`. Unfortunately, this is a limitation of all approaches to debugging: you can be looking right at the problem, but if you don't know what you're looking for, you may not see it. A good strategy is to take a break and come back later with fresh eyes. (Well, assuming you've given yourself enough time for that to be feasible.)
  - Actually this is really two mistakes, not just one: there are at least two completely separate ways that `i <= pivotIndex && pivotIndex <= j` can become false. And I think you really do need that assumption to remain true. (That is, the problem isn't that you're making the assumption, it's that you're not satisfying it.)
  - In addition to fixing this issue, you might consider making use of assertions and validations so that your code blows up as soon as it gets into a bad state. (That said, it can be hard to think of useful assertions to include in the middle of a complex unit of code. Figuring out the right assertions is not much easier than simply noticing the bug to begin with. So, dunno.)
- The `list.swap(pivotIndex, i)` near the end is not well-motivated. Rather, it looks like that was tacked on to try to patch over a bug? If so, then — you should always root-cause bugs in order to fix them, rather than try to work around them without understanding what happened. Otherwise you can never be sure that your workaround fully solves the problem (and in my experience, you can generally be sure that it *doesn't*).

I think you can see, by the way, why I don't share Amit's love of debuggers. Your debugging output showed you the bug, but you didn't see it; you would probably have gotten the same result with a debugger. (If anything, a debugger would likely have made it even harder to see the big picture.) That said, I do think you should give debuggers a try; many people do find them useful, and it never hurts to have another weapon in your arsenal. And when the problem is that you simply aren't noticing an issue, who knows but that seeing the same thing in two different ways (in debugging output and in a debugger) may increase the chances that you'll notice it once?

Comment: I completely missed the point by using JUnit tests while keeping the method private! I'll keep this in mind henceforth.

Comment: As for the third mistake, I am now convinced that the second swap is not needed. I think I got confused with the different variations of the quick sort algorithm. The way I'm seeing it is that one approach is to swap the `pivot` element with `i` (or `j`) at the end of the loop(which I tried) while the other is to return the index of `i`(or `j`). I think the mistake I made is that with the first approach, either the first(or last) element is chosen as the pivot **or** the pivot(middle element in my case) is swapped to one of the ends.

Comment: With regards to the second mistake you pointed out, I'm not entirely convinced that my algorithm works on the assumption `i <= pivotIndex && pivotIndex <= j` or maybe, I'm not seeing it just yet; in which case, I could, as you suggested, use a break. Also, correct me if I'm wrong but the first part of that assumption i.e. `i <= pivotIndex` is true which  _is_  rather essential to my algorithm.  My understanding at present is that at given time, (elements to the left of `i`) < the `pivot` element while (elements to the right of `j`) >= the `pivot` element (...continued in the next comment)

Comment: On inspecting the code I found that in the `if(i < j)` block, `j` will never be equal to the index due to the `j--` statement in the preceding `while`. So the `else if(j == pivotIndex)` block is unnecessary.  Two cases come to mind: 1) `i` reaches the pivot before `j`  2) `j` crosses the pivot before 'i' (...continued in the next comment)

Comment: The list in the first case can be modelled as follows (**Note:** P denotes element at `pivotIndex`,--> is used to show where `i` or `j` point to): **[(<P) 'i'-->(P) (elements in random order i.e. < or > or = P) 'j'-->(a single element < P) (>=P)]**...`list.swap(i, j)` is called...`pivotIndex` changes to `j` and the list now looks like: **[(<P) `i`-->(<, >, = P)<--`j` (P) (>=P) ]**. My point being although `j` <= `pivotIndex`, subsequent calls to `list.swap(i, j)` are necessary to put random keys in the (<, >, = P) block in order after which `i` should be returned  by the `partition` method.

Comment: The list in the second case can be modelled as the second list mentioned above.

Comment: @ByteMan2021, yes! its lot of debugging! Not only debugger, I traced it on paper :D However, I have posted the working code. You mark it accepted if it works as expected! I tried executing many scenarios. It din't fail for any, so far.

Comment: @ruakh I just unit tested the `partition` method and found out you were right all along! I do indeed need `i <= pivotIndex && pivotIndex <= j` to be true for my algorithm to work :P

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @ruakh pointed out, I observed that pivot can stay in any part of the array after `partition()` is called. However, since element at pivot index is sorted for sure, which can even be at extreme ends of the `list`; conditionally invoking `quicksort()` should solve your problem. Also, keeping in mind the edge cases already highlighted in @ruakh's answer, following code should address all your problems. I have tested this routine infinitely for any breaking case, couldn't find any so far.

**Quick Sort method:**

```
private void quicksort(int firstIndex, int lastIndex) {
            //System.out.println(indent + "quicksort(" + firstIndex + ", " + lastIndex + ")");
            //indent+="  ";
            if(firstIndex < lastIndex) {
                int p = partition(firstIndex, lastIndex);
                //System.out.println(indent + "p = " + p);
                if (firstIndex < p - 1)
                    quicksort(firstIndex, p - 1);
                if (p < lastIndex)
                    quicksort(p, lastIndex);
            }
//            indent = indent.substring(2);
        }
```

**Partition Method:**

```
private int partition(int firstIndex, int lastIndex) {
            //System.out.println(indent + "Inside partition(" + firstIndex + ", " + lastIndex + ")");
            int pivotIndex = (firstIndex + lastIndex) / 2;
            //System.out.println(indent + "pivotIndex = " + pivotIndex);
            int i = firstIndex;
            int j = lastIndex;
            while (i <= j) {
                while(list.compare(i, pivotIndex, comparator) < 0) {
                    i++;
                }
                while(list.compare(j, pivotIndex, comparator) > 0) {
                    j--;
                }
                //System.out.println(indent + "Initially: " + list.toString());
                //System.out.println(indent + "i = " + i +", pivotIndex = " + pivotIndex + ", j = " + j);
                if(i <= j) {
                    list.swap(i, j);
                    //System.out.println(indent + "After 1st swap: " + list.toString());
                    if(i == pivotIndex) {
                        pivotIndex = j;
                        //System.out.println(indent + "Pivot was swapped");
                    }
                    else if(j == pivotIndex) {
                        pivotIndex = i;
                        //System.out.println(indent + "Pivot was swapped");
                    }
                        i++;
                        j--;
                    //System.out.println(indent + "i = " + i +", pivotIndex = " + pivotIndex + ", j = " + j);
                }
            }
//            list.swap(pivotIndex, i);
            //System.out.println(indent + "After 2nd swap: " + list.toString());
            //System.out.println(indent + "i = " + i +", pivotIndex = " + pivotIndex + ", j = " + j);
            return i;
        }
```

Please note that I haven't changed other parts of your code, which is commented out or any other methods

**Tester class:**

```
package test;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test
{

    private static final Comparator<Integer> INTEGER_COMPARATOR = new IntegerComparator();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwapList<Integer> customList;
        AbstractSorter<Integer> customSorter;
        do {
            Random r = new Random();
            int length = r.nextInt(10);
            Integer[] test = new Integer[length];
            for(int j = 0; j < length; j++)
                test[j] = r.nextInt(10);
            customList = new ArrayBasedSwapList<Integer>(test);
            customSorter = new QuickSorter<Integer>(customList,
                    INTEGER_COMPARATOR);
            SwapList<Integer> result = customSorter.sort();
            if(!result.isSorted(INTEGER_COMPARATOR)) {
              System.out.println("Result: " + result.toString());
              System.out.println(result.isSorted(INTEGER_COMPARATOR));
            }
        } while(true);
    }

}
```

Feel free to comment any test case that fails and I will try to fix that.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this is a good answer. The OP is obviously engaged in an educational exercise (probably for a class); simply fixing his/her code for him/her, without even fully explaining what you're doing and why, is not helpful.

Comment: Your code works, no doubt. I agree with @ruakh though; I noticed that you removed the two `i < j` conditions in the inner `while` loops. It appears to me that you've changed the original algorithm by doing so, introduced a new problem (possibility of going out of bounds), necessitating the conditional invocation of `quicksort()` which you then claim "should solve" ***my*** "problem". Anyways, after tinkering with the code a bit, I was able to fix the algorithm. I'll update the question to include the fix. All that remains (the most important part I think) is to understand why the fix works.